# Pushing and popping a view controller fast many times crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a view controller A with a lot of items for the user to chose among. The user can press on it and this will push another view controller B.
The user can then go back a chose a different item.

This goes fine 90% of the times, but if the user is fast and does it at lot of times the app crashes with the error message :

> "terminated due to memory error"

.

This view controller B is a big one, so I cannot really post any code, but I have check for retained object, memory leaks with no luck. My theory is  that the garbage collector cannot follow the pace, so I might have to wrap a `@autoreleasepool` around my objects

Do you have any good ideas / practices?

**UPDATE:**

Try do this. Take a random view controller and add this

```
MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 500, 500)];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Push this view controller and pop it. Repeat for around 15 times and the app will crash.

Comment: do you use "pushViewController:View  animated:YES" ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding a back button and when pressing this, I manually removed the mapview and reference. I would have expected the iOS to do this automatically, but this seems to work for me.